# How do I get a channel's topic using discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I know you are able to do `channel.setTopic('asdfs')` to *set* a channels topic, but I want to get it.

I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
if (message.channel.topic == 'asdf') {
//do stuff
}
```

**How can I *get* the channel topic?**

Comment: `console.log(message.channel.topic)` --> observe console for results

Comment: What didn't work? The comparison? Maybe the topic isn't `asdf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking to see if the text channel's topic is equal to something, then you are correct in what you did however it should of been this:

```
if (message.channel.topic === 'string') {
// your code
}
```